# Padding between border and text in textframe InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, borders

Is there a way in InDesign CS6 to add space between the text and its border? Or do I have to just make a shape behind the text instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ctrl+shift+b (text frame options dialog), then set your desired text inset

Comment: In InDesign CC, the keyboard shortcut is just **Ctrl-B** (on Windows).

Answer (score 6):

In the "**Text Frame Options**" dialog box you can adjust the "**Inset Spacing**" for a text box.

In InDesign CC 2014 on Mac you can find this dialog box by going to **Object > Text Frame Options** or using the shortcut **command+b**.